# Cordova UWP Desktop - hide back arrow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

Using Cordova I'm targeting Windows Desktop (specifically Windows 10). In my `deviceready` event, I have the following code:

```
document.addEventListener( "backbutton", function() {
  window.history.back();
}, false );
```

This hooks up the back arrow in the top left hand corner of the window and works a treat. However, I would like to hide the arrow for the first screen. Is there a way to conditionally hide the back arrow based on the page I'm currently on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I would like to hide the arrow for the first screen. Is there a way to conditionally hide the back arrow based on the page I'm currently on?

On any page of your application, you can call the following API to hide the back button again:

```
var Core = Windows.UI.Core;
Core.SystemNavigationManager.getForCurrentView().appViewBackButtonVisibility = Core.AppViewBackButtonVisibility.collapsed;
```

Comment: Awesome. Looks like I have to set this to visible on subsequent pages? Is there an event I can hook into that fires on the load for every page where I can write this code once?

Comment: [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) is a good place for you to place the codes.

Comment: In the case of an SPA - `window.onload` will only fire once?

Comment: If you are using SPA in your application, `window.onload` can only be fired once. You can place the codes in `onload` event of your sub page elements(ex: `Div.onload` if the root of your sub page is a div element).

Comment: Just realised this. Sorry, I'm getting dyslexic between Cordova and Angular. Thanks for the advice!